# Flutter Web send pdf file to a WhatsApp contact using URL Launcher

Tags: android, flutter, whatsapp, url-launcher

I have implemented a void function to launch WhatsApp in Flutter Web using URL Launcher. However my goal is to pass a pdf file to a WhatsApp contact and not the text HelloWorld. Does anyone know how I go about it and should I convert the pdf file to Uri and then parse as a string?

```
 void _openWhatsApp(String phoneNumberControllerText) async {
    String phoneNumber = phoneNumberControllerText;
    var url = 'https://wa.me/${phoneNumber}?text=HelloWorld';
    await launch(url);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to share the PDF,
check out this package [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus)

Comment: Not sure if share plus is helping at this point

Comment: socialshare package works fine , but how to use that for pdf ?